# Disable setting User-Agent in javascript code generated by openapi-generator-cli

Tags: javascript, openapi, openapi-generator

In the context of a Vue.js frontend, it seems that the javascript client code generated by `openapi-generator-cli` is trying to set the User-Agent which gives the following error in Google Chrome:

`Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"`

How can I configure `openapi-generator-cli` so that it doesn't try to set the User-Agent?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/6f413f6aca5e456a877150c49fb36f7b4c84e5fd/modules/openapi-generator-cli/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen/cmd/Generate.java#L388), it looks like the user agent is only added if this argument is included. Otherwise it should be omitted. Check to make sure you aren't including this flag.

Alternatively, can to modify the [source code of the project](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/6f413f6aca5e456a877150c49fb36f7b4c84e5fd/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen/config/CodegenConfigurator.java#L318) to prevent the user agent from being added one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a "User-Agent" header is always added to the generated `ApiClient.js`, at least in `version 6.2.0`.

It is set to either a non-empty value specified in the generator configuration, or, if no such value is provided, to a default one.
Excerpt from `ApiClient.js`:

```
// constructor:
this.defaultHeaders = {
    'User-Agent': 'OpenAPI-Generator/1.0/Javascript'
};

// callApi:      
request.set(this.defaultHeaders).set(this.normalizeParams(headerParams));
```

However, the generated resource-specific api clients can be ammended after creating them, to unset the default headers, like in the below example (assuming an api client generated for a resource named `Resource`):

```
    const ResourceClientApi = new ResourceApiClient();
    const resourceApi = resourceClientApi.getResourceApi();
    resourceApi.apiClient.defaultHeaders = {};
```

Then simply using the resourceApi as usual:

```
resourceApi.getResource().then(...);
```